# Devise logging inaccurate IP address on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, geolocation

Using the Devise `trackable` module with Heroku, I've noticed that the IPs that get recorded are incorrect due to Heroku's forwarding. The correct ip gets stored in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` but Devise uses `REMOTE_ADDR`, which is screwing up my Geolocating. Is there any way to tell Devise to use `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` without modifying the Gem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an old version of Devise maybe? I don't see what you're seeing on my Heroku apps - I see my IP address that whatsmyip is reporting in `current_sign_in_ip` and `last_sign_in_ip` fields. There's code in devise from 2 years ago that added tests for it https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/d11402612f5779349afb79b0c90d2e4dbef1489c

Comment: Okay, I've made some progress here. Looks like it's not Heroku, but Cloudflare that's giving me trouble. That said, still not really sure why. I think it may be putting the correct address in HTTP_X_REAL_IP instead of HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. I have it working fine with Cloudflare disabled. Might end up just leaving it that way.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480047/heroku-geolocation-always-returns-seattle-wa#answer-5503842), you'd have to set `trusted_proxies`.

In Rails 3/4 you can probably do it in application.rb, using `config`:

```
config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = ['<< Heroku load balancer IP >>']
```

Comment: Isn't the load balancer IP liable to change though?

Comment: @StephenCorwin I don't know, you should check it on Heroku.

Comment: Yeah, the load balancers have pretty dynamic addresses. I thought about just trusting all IPs, but then it loses my actual IP somehow. Wondering if maybe I can tap into Devise's sessions controller somehow.

Comment: @StephenCorwin how about the regexp, as in linked answer?